# EF Code First Migrations for multiple databases

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I have prototyped a project using EF 6 Code First MVC 5 based on this solution:

[EF Code First to create multiple databases dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25300828/ef-code-first-to-create-multiple-databases-dynamically/25301014)

Now I would like to know how Migrations would work with multiple databases?

Does it mean I am going to need to run the Add-Migration MigrationsName for every database I have?

Comment: Will all databases always have the same version?

Comment: If you mean the same schema, yes.

Comment: I mean, could 1 database have newer version from the others, e.g. you just add `Code` column, and does it need to be applied to all databases, or only specific database?

Comment: To all, they all should be the same, shared by the same application/project

Answer (score 2):

You just confirmed that all databases need to be upgraded the same time, then you only need to use one database to add the migration, then update it to all databases.

You can specify the connection string name parameter based on connection string name in the config.

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="CompanyABC"
         connectionString="Data Source=.; Initial Catalog=CompanyABC; Integrated Security = true;" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="CompanyDEF"
         connectionString="Data Source=.; Initial Catalog=CompanyDEF; Integrated Security = true;"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="CompanyXYZ"
         connectionString="Data Source=.; Initial Catalog=CompanyXYZ; Integrated Security = true;"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

**Migration**

```
PM> Enable-Migrations -ConnectionStringName CompanyABC
PM> Add-Migration UpgradeToVersionX -ConnectionStringName CompanyABC
PM> Update-Database -ConnectionStringName CompanyABC
PM> Update-Database -ConnectionStringName CompanyDEF
PM> Update-Database -ConnectionStringName CompanyXYZ
```

**Run Migration at Runtime**

```
Database.SetInitializer<AppContext>(
   new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<AppContext, Configuration>());
```

Comment: Thanks Yuliam, I forgot to mentioned that I will have a new database for each new client. Today I may have 10, tomorrow 10000, so I would need an automate way to go with code first

Comment: This still works, as long as you pass the connection string as new database, the migration folder will contain sequential upgrade from initial database until latest version, you just need to execute it to specific database

Comment: but that wouldnt require to have all the existing dbs in the web config as connection strings? How would I have control of that, I could have a new db created every hour. Also, I would need to run this Update-Database -ConnectionStringName CompanyABC manually? that could be Company1 ~ Company10000. I not getting how this process would run automatically

Comment: you can pass the connection string value, `-ConnectionString "Data Source=.; Initial Catalog=Company1000; Integrated Security=true" -ConnectionProviderName "System.Data.SqlClient"`

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking now, do you want to have automatic migration ?

Comment: This sounds like I would need to have all the connections string in the web config? I would like to set the connection string at runtime as per your previous suggestion for the other question

Comment: if you want to set connection at runtime then you need to also run the migration at runtime, `Database.SetInitializer<YourContext>(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<YourContext, Configuration>());`